# How to render a Content Object from tt_content in my extension with PHP in Typo3 6.1.5

Tags: database, plugins, typo3, frontend, typo3-6.1.x

I need to render with my extension a specific content from tt_content.

How can I do this?

\TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer ?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you want to do, what the result should look like, what you tried to make it work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Extbase extensions `$this->cObj` is no more available in the current scope, so you need to get it first before you can use:

```
$cObj = $this->configurationManager->getContentObject();

$ttContentConfig = array(
    'tables'       => 'tt_content',
    'source'       => 123,
    'dontCheckPid' => 1
);

$content .= $cObj->RECORDS($ttContentConfig);
```

Comment: Result is:  Fatal error: Call to a member function RECORDS() on a non-object in ......

Comment: @dusty then the question is why `$this->cObj` dont give you a cObject.    In a normal ext. `$this->cObj` should give you a cObject. You can try: `t3lib_div::makeInstance('tslib_cObj')->RECORDS($tt_content_conf);` If that does not work you have to post more information about your extention

Comment: @dusty and nbar, you should put more attention to differences between `pi_base` coding and Extbase

Comment: @biesior You are right. My solution was for pi_base. When you work with Extbase then you should take Daniels soltuion with the fluid cObject. In this case your edit on my post implicate that this is still the way to go even with extbase and I am not sure if that is helpfull.

Comment: @nbar  Why? Daniel's solution considers that you know `yourPid` and `yourContentElementID` at the runtime (so it's just hardcoded). I have other case: with BE module I'm creating tt_content's of different type on one page but for different parent-records of my ext. Front-end plugins displays only selected contents depending on UID current of displayed parent-record. With TS this task couldn't be completed, with the one you showed (and I edited) it's possible to iterate through DB results to fetch only required contents. Finally I don't see a reason for using redundant TS when not required...

Comment: @biesior And again you are right ;) So you would render the content for example in the block and give the $content to the Fluid template for output.

Comment: @nbar that's exactly what I'm doing, works like a charm and I have wild bunch of possibilities in meantime, which are unavailable via TS

Comment: @biesior Yes I get it. Maybe it would be nice to create a ViewHelper with this code, so you dont have the code in your block and a designer can render whatever content he want without the developer have to change anything. http://www.in2code.de/community/snippet-datenbank/snippets/detail/content-element-viewhelper-um-seiteninhalte-in-fluid-zu-rendern/ - I not yet worked with ViewHelper but I am reading right now about it.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it from the controller too. If I understood your question, you may want to try this

```php
$cObject = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Typoscript [CONTENT object](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Content/Index.html) and pass it to a fluid ViewHelper:

```
lib.myContent = CONTENT
lib.myContent {
  table = tt_content
  select {
    pidInList = yourPid
    where = uid=yourContentElementID
  }
}
```

In your extension using Fluid:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.myContent" />
```

You can also pass values through the viewHelper, see [here](https://stmllr.net/blog/combining-fluid-viewhelpers-and-typoscript-in-typo3-5-basic-examples//)

Comment: This link is dead. Do you have this ViewHelper?

Answer (score 1):

Following script will be use PI base extension.

```
$uid = $this->cObj->data['uid'];

if ($this->cObj->data['_LOCALIZED_UID']) {
    $uid = $this->cObj->data['_LOCALIZED_UID'];
}
```

Following script will be use in EXT BASE extension.

```
$this->contentObj = $this->configurationManager->getContentObject();
$uid = $this->contentObj->data['uid'];
```

For more information about TYPO3 stuff you may visit my [blog](https://jainishsenjaliya.wordpress.com/)

https://jainishsenjaliya.wordpress.com/2014/08/21/how-to-get-current-tt_content-uid-in-pi-base-and-extbase-extension/