# How to render INT_SCRIPT in StandaloneView?

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

I'm rendering in an standalone view a TypoScript Object with the cObject ViewHelper. That TS Object gets tt_content from other pages currently. But the result has the INT_SCRIPT markers and not the real content.

here's my code on how to make the standalone view, the template and the TypoScript:

Inside controller:

```
public function renderStandaloneView($template = 'View/Show', $variables = array(), $fileExt = 'html', $noCache = TRUE) {
    if ( $noCache === TRUE ) $GLOBALS['TSFE']->set_no_cache();

    // Get standalone view
    $configuration = $this->configurationManager->getConfiguration(ConfigurationManagerInterface::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_FRAMEWORK);
    $view          = $this->objectManager->get(StandaloneView::class);

    $view->getRequest()->setControllerExtensionName($this->extensionName);
    $view->setFormat($fileExt);
    $view->setLayoutRootPaths($configuration['view']['layoutRootPaths']);
    $view->setPartialRootPaths($configuration['view']['partialRootPaths']);
    $view->setTemplateRootPaths($configuration['view']['templateRootPaths']);
    $view->setTemplate($template);

    // Render view
    $view->assignMultiple($variables);

    return $view->render();
}
```

TypoScript:

```
lib.myContent = COA
lib.myContent {
  10 = CONTENT
  10 {
    table = tt_content

    select {
        orderBy         = sorting
        where           = 0
        where.wrap      = colPos=|
        pidInList.field = uid
    }
  }
}
```

Fluid:

```
<f:for each="{myvars}" as="myvar" iteration="it">
  <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.myContent" data="{uid:'{myvar.uid}'}" />
</f:for>
```

I cannot change all the uncached elements (like content elements / plugins) on that pages to be cached.

So how can i parse the standalone view including the non cached content and not insert the INT_SCRIPT markers?

Thanks for anything!

Comment: I don‘t think this will fix the whole of your problem but nonetheless you should start  removing `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->set_no_cache()` from your method. This will disable all page cache for the current request. Don‘t use this `set_no_cache` for **anything** you want to release to the wild!

Comment: Thanks for that hint. I've changed it. As expected it didn't resolves my problem.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out what you're trying to do here for the past 10 minutes. Without avail.  This condition: if ( $noCache === TRUE ) $GLOBALS['TSFE']->set_no_cache(); obviously can't work. Because if your content is cached once, the condition wont even be checked anymore. The call to ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin in your ext_localconf.php defines, per action, if the content is cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. Maybe it isn't the best way to resolve that problem. But at the moment it works fine.

```
public function renderStandaloneView($template = 'View/Show', $variables = array(), $fileExt = 'html') {
    // Get standalone view
    $configuration = $this->configurationManager->getConfiguration(ConfigurationManagerInterface::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_FRAMEWORK);
    $view          = $this->objectManager->get(StandaloneView::class);

    $view->getRequest()->setControllerExtensionName($this->extensionName);
    $view->setFormat($fileExt);
    $view->setLayoutRootPaths($configuration['view']['layoutRootPaths']);
    $view->setPartialRootPaths($configuration['view']['partialRootPaths']);
    $view->setTemplateRootPaths($configuration['view']['templateRootPaths']);
    $view->setTemplate($template);

    // Render view
    $view->assignMultiple($variables);

    // Handle the INT_SCRIPT markers
    $content = $view->render();
    $contentBak = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->content;
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->content = $content;
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->INTincScript();
    $content = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->content;
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->content = $contentBak;
    unset($contentBak);

    return $content;
}
```

For your information. I need this to handle content from pages and send them by mail or render a pdf with an external tool. But some content or pages are only available for the current user (not a group or another user). And i didn't want to login that user inside the controller or else. i think that's the best case to handle that.

Other solutions are still welcome :-)

Comment: Why didn't you say so? You're invoking a StandaloneView just to invoke TypoScript for content rendering. Holy crap. This is how you render content from inside an Extension: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283998/how-i-can-render-content-object-from-tt-content-i-my-extension-with-php-in-typo3

Comment: Yeah i know it looks like a "holy crap", just to render TypoScript. I can not explain you the whole project, but in my case it's needed to use it over the StandaloneView way. Thanks a lot for your hint anyway!

Alternative way (like your way) could be just call the contentRendererObject and use FLUIDTEMPLATE in the TS Object.

Answer (score 0):

As you're rendering the content from multiple pages, I recommend doing a proper sub-request and rendering with a custom PAGE object.

The following TypoScript setup renders a page's content but without the whole surrounding markup (html, body, head, etc).

```
pageOnlyContent = PAGE
pageOnlyContent {
  typeNum = 11695
  
  config.disableAllHeaderCode = 1
  config.index_enable = 0
  
  1 = CONTENT
  1.table = tt_content
  1.select {
    where = {#colPos}=0
    orderBy = sorting
  }
}
```

Next you need a ViewHelper that does the sub-request.

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\RequestFactory;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\Headers;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\ServerRequestFactory;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Site\SiteFinder;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\Traits\CompileWithRenderStatic;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\Rendering\RenderingContextInterface;

class GetPageContentViewHelper extends AbstractViewHelper
{
    use CompileWithRenderStatic;

    public function initializeArguments() {
        $this->registerArgument('pageUid', 'int', 'The page to render');
    }

    public static function renderStatic(
        array $arguments,
        \Closure $renderChildrenClosure,
        RenderingContextInterface $renderingContext
    ) {
        $queryParameters = ['type' => 11695];
        $siteUrl = ServerRequestFactory::fromGlobals()->getHeaderLine('Origin');
        $site = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(SiteFinder::class)->getSiteByPageId($arguments['pageUid']);
        $url = $site->getRouter()->generateUri($arguments['pageUid'], $queryParameters);
        $response = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(RequestFactory::class)->request($siteUrl . $url);

    if ($response->getStatusCode() >= 300) {
        $content = $response->getReasonPhrase();
    } else {
        $content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
    }
    return $content;
}
```

}

Your Fluid template then becomes something like

```
<f:for each="{myvars}" as="myvar" iteration="it">
  <mynamespace:getPageContent pageUid="{myvar.uid}" />
</f:for>
```

Works on 11 LTS.

Comment: yo @Geee, not that I don't appreciate you editing the code sample, but the initial version with PageLinkBuilder does the whole dance with Site and correct domain internally.
As it is now the solution seems a little too specific for a certain use case, without stating what that use case is.

Comment: Ah, right, PageLinkBuilder only works in FE context.