# TYPO3 render uncached content element on a dedicated page

Tags: typo3

I would like to render a page which *just* has a `tt_content` element on it (so I can Ajax it into another page). However, due to the way it needs to be set up, this content element needs to remain *uncached* until rendered.

The same plugin renders perfectly fine when adding via TYPO3, however I want to be able to taget this plugin via JavaScript (without having to load the whole page again).

How can I render the content on the page? When I do the following I get the uncached `INT_SCRIPT`  marker - is there anyway I can force this to render on page load (or make it a “cached” element when selected?

```
$content = $TSFE->cObj->cObjGetSingle('RECORDS', [
  'tables' => 'tt_content',
  'source' => 123
]);
$response->getBody()->write($content);
```

I'm using TYPO3 9.5.

Thanks for any help in advance.

(I found this but the solution doesn't work: [How to render INT_SCRIPT in StandaloneView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42936330/how-to-render-int-script-in-standaloneview)

Answer (score 0):

You could work with a simple uncached page setup provided as another page type and then target that page with your AJAX call.

A solution for that approach has been provided here: [TYPO3 Ajax Page Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21884878/typo3-ajax-page-configuration)